# Caption indexing on the subfigure itself

Tags: subfloats, subcaption, floating

I'm using \subfigure package with some code like that:

```
\begin{figure}
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graph1}
         \caption{$y=x$}
         \label{fig:y equals x}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graph2}
         \caption{$y=3sinx$}
         \label{fig:three sin x}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graph3}
         \caption{$y=5/x$}
         \label{fig:five over x}
     \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Three simple graphs}
        \label{fig:three graphs}
\end{figure}
```

I want to locate the caption enumerator on the image itself, for example:
[image]

with the following parameters: bold, capital letters (sc for example, I couldn't find a good way to merge sc and bf together) and square brackets.

Any idea how can I define something like that?

Thank you!

Comment: If you were using the subfigure package, your code would not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to vertically overlay something is to use `\raisebox`, both to change the baseline and to `\smash` the height.  However, `\caption` has to go into a `minipage`, `\parbox` or `\vbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\Alph{subfigure}}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{weird}{\textbf{[#2]}}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=weird, labelsep=quad}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{singlelinecheck=false}
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
         \raisebox{\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\begin{minipage}[b]{\dimexpr \linewidth-1em}
           \caption{$y=x$}
           \label{fig:y equals x}
         \end{minipage}}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
         \raisebox{\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\parbox[b]{\dimexpr \linewidth-1em}{%
           \caption{$y=3\sin x$}
           \label{fig:three sin x}
         }}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
         \raisebox{\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\advance\hsize by -1em\vbox{%
           \caption{$y=5/x$}
           \label{fig:five over x}
         }}
     \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Three simple graphs}
        \label{fig:three graphs}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

Another approach is to use negative `\vspace`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\Alph{subfigure}}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{brackets}{\textbf{[#2]}}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=brackets, labelsep=quad}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{singlelinecheck=false}
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
         \vskip-\abovecaptionskip\vskip-\baselineskip
         \begin{minipage}[b]{\dimexpr \linewidth-1em}
           \caption{$y=x$}
           \label{fig:y equals x}
         \end{minipage}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
         \vskip-\abovecaptionskip\vskip-\baselineskip
         \parbox[b]{\dimexpr \linewidth-1em}{%
           \caption{$y=3\sin x$}
           \label{fig:three sin x}
         }
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
         \vskip-\abovecaptionskip\vskip-\baselineskip
         \makebox[\linewidth]{\advance\hsize by -1em\vbox{% \centering ineffective
           \caption{$y=5/x$}
           \label{fig:five over x}
         }}
     \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Three simple graphs}
        \label{fig:three graphs}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you John! I have more questions if you don't mind: 
1. How can I move the overly caption a bit right? Lets say for your first option in example
2. Is there ay way I can design the caption's index with bold, capital letters and square brackets? something like that: **[A]**

Comment: You can use `\captionsetup` to make formatting changes.  See the caption package manual. (more details than the subcaption manual).  You can also move then entire minipage to the right (`\centering`) by making it smaller.

Comment: Hey! I'm familiar with `\captionsetup` options but I couldn't find a way to combine **bold** (`\textbf`) with Small Caps (`\textsc`) formatting together. They override each over.. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do you need small caps, or just caps (\Alph)?

Comment: Just caps. How can I choose caps enumerator while using subfigures?

Comment: Check the new versions above.

Comment: Hi! about the new version - my caption is a bit long and now part of my caption is lost (and covering the page enumerator), do you have any idea how to split the caption into the next page, using your sub-figures solution?

Comment: Not automatically.  You can put the caption into a different figure environment.  You may need `\ContinuedFloat` (caption package).